# How to revert a dual boot (windows 8 & Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 15.04, windows-8

I want to reinstall ubuntu but with LTS so I can delete windows 8 and allocate my hard drive data to ubuntu

Comment: There should be an option in the installer to "Erase Everything and Install Ubuntu" in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest LTS Version (14.04) and follow the installation wizard. 
There is an option to use the whole disk and erase (!) everything that's on it.